# What is the best way to simulate Lidar for ROS2? Having problems

Tags: gazebo, ros2, simulation, lidar

I have been trying to work out how to simulate a LiDAR using ROS2 / Gazebo, however I am having trouble getting anything to work properly. I am using ROS2-humble and IGN gazebo fortress

I have tried 2 different methods:

#### Trying using a SDF file of the robot and Lidar in Gazebo

I have a SDF file that includes this description under a `<model>` tag:

```
 <sensor name='gpu_lidar' type='gpu_lidar'>" <pose relative_to='lidar_frame'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <topic>lidar</topic>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>640</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-1.396263</min_angle>
            <max_angle>1.396263</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>1</samples>
            <resolution>0.01</resolution>
            <min_angle>0</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.08</min>
          <max>10.0</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
      </ray>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
    </sensor>
```

I run this in gazebo. However, I don't notice any visualization of the LiDAR data. See here:

[image]

There is no LiDAR visualization in Gazebo. I checked on the gazebo topic `/lidar` and data does appear to be being published. I tried to visualize this in `rviz2`, by adding a `ros-gz-bridge` for the `/lidar` topic. However when I open rviz and add a laser-scan for this topic, nothing shows up

### Trying creating a ros2 URDF that defines a gazebo Lidar

I tried following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJZXRncGaGM, where I create a ROS2 package, defining my robot using a URDF file, and then adding a link with this description:

```
<gazebo reference="lidar_link">
<material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
<sensor name="laser" type="ray">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
    <visualise>true</visualise>
    <update_rate>10</update_rate>
    <ray>
        <scan>
            <horizontal>
                <samples>360</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>-3.14</min_angle>
                <max_angle>3.14</max_angle>
            </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
            <min>0.1</min>
            <max>12</max>
            <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
    </ray>
    <plugin name="laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
        <ros>
            <argument>~/out:=scan</argument>
        </ros>
        <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
        <frame_name>laser_link</frame_name>
    </plugin>
</sensor>
```

I run this using a launch file and then ran rviz. The `/scan`  ros2 topic was displaying an empty laserScan message, and nothing could be seen in rviz or gazebo, see below:

[image]

Here I am defining the environment to be scanned in the URDF file as well.

#### Question

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? How can I correctly simulate and visualize a LIDAR?

EDIT:
It turns out that in Gazebo, the Lidar is not visualized by default, so you must launch Gazebo and search "visualize Lidar" in the top right to bring up the menu. Also the <render_engine> tag must be set to "ogre2" and I removed the sensor plugin in the world file (It is now only in the URDF file)